# Google maps api 3 Directions

Tags: google-maps, directions

I have a map with several markers on them.
Now I want to use directions from one to another, without knowing the begin or the end point.
Can I let Google decide what is the beginning?

What I have is for example 5 positions on the map and I don't know the the begin and endpoint is! So I choose a begin and end point randomly and let Google make a route. The problem is that ,because of the random begin and end point, is that the route google generates is quit unlogical. Can it be optimized what to take as an start and end?

Comment: You should provide more detail on this question, as it does not appear to be answerable in its current state.

Comment: you need more than a begin and end point for more than two points, how is it supposed to determine what the sequence is? The computer isn't psychic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anwser is easier than I thought ;-) Just take the same point for the start and the end. Google create a nice optimized closed route when using waypoints.